# Can I run -c in batch mode (without opening the curses display)?

Tags: ex-mode, argument-list

I find myself performing a small shell loop (involving `vim`) to transform files into the correct line endings for my system.  It looks as follows:

```
for i in *; do vim -c 'set ff=dos' -c 'wq' $i; done
```

It works.  The problem is that the terminal flashes during the loop as vim **opens and closes repeatedly**.  There should be a more elegant way to perform this.

---

#### Attempt 1 (-e -s)

I tried `-e` and `-s` from `:h arguments`

```
for i in *; do vim -e -s -c 'set ff=dos' -c 'wq' $i; done
```

but it is not doing what I believed it would do. `set ff=` is an `ex` command alright, and the command above works if I do not include `-s`.  But if I leave `-s` out it opens and closes vim just like the original command.

---

#### Attempt 2 (:argdo)

I'm afraid of `argdo` because I never understood how it can perform changes to several buffers without writing them back to disk.  And I just run into this exact issue in this attempt.  I open all files with `vim *` and try:

```
:argdo set ff=unix
```

But after changing the current file I get:

```
E37: No write since last change (add ! to override)
```

---

I'm probably missing something simple in both attempts.  I'm very keen on finding a good solution for attempt 1, since it is easier to automate.

What is the elegant way of performing such a multi-file conversion in vim?

Comment: If you just want to change the newlines to DOS newlines, maybe Vim is a bit of a clunky tool for it on the command line?

Comment: @Kusalananda - Whelp, yeah it is kind of brute forcing it. I have a `sed` script to perform that as well but it does not work properly on AIX.  And i cannot be arsed to compile GNU sed on AIX (i already managed to compile vim and it was enough of a pain).

Comment: Does the shell program `unix2dos` work for you?

Comment: @wbg my biggest problem with `dos` encoding is on AIX, and AIX misses a lot of programs common to linux distros, `unix2dos` is one of them.  Yes, using AIX (and HP-UX) today is crap, i know, but it isn't me who decides.

Comment: I hate when a *nix doesn't have a common tool I rely upon. It might not be hard to compile versus getting vim to compile.

Comment: git clone git://git.code.sf.net/p/dos2unix/dos2unix dos2unix-dos2unix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following, it is nearly what you have done (using another example to see difference), you need to add the `hidden` option:

```
$ touch a b c
$ cat *
$ vi * +"set hidden" +"argdo r\!ls" +"xall"
$ cat *

a
b
c

a
b
c

a
b
c
```

`set hidden` tells vim you can switch buffer without saving them.

If you still want to use your loop, you can do the same:

```
for i in *; do vim +"r\!ls" +"x" $i; done
```

Comment: Do you have something about changing buffers without writing them to disk in your `vimrc`?  When i try to replicate your example only the first file receives the output from `ls`. Then before vim closes (due to `xall`) `E37: No write since last change (add ! to override)` quickly flashes through the screen (terminal scroll locks are a blessing).  I'm actually doing `vim * +'argdo r!ls' +'xall'` because i have not `vi` alias, but that shall not make a difference.

Comment: Yeah you are right, I have `set hidden`, let me add that.

Answer (score 1):

I already accepted an answer but I found a simpler way to perform this.  Given a couple of files:

```
$ echo yay > a
$ echo yay > b
$ echo yay > c
$ file *
a: ASCII text
b: ASCII text
c: ASCII text
```

I can use the several `:argdo` commands separated by `|`, this way I do not need to rely on `:set hidden`:

```
$ vim -u NONE -c 'argdo set ff=dos | w' -c 'q' *
$ file *
a: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
b: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
c: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
```

It works similar to `:set hidden` + `:xall` in terms of how the command appears on the screen but it writes the files one by one.

Comment: Nice, you should accept your answer instead of mine :)